# Advantage of nullable Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, conventions

I need to build a table for some new components that will keep track of available and used inventory.  It will be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE components
(
   component_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   workOrder_Id int FOREIGN KEY,
   componentSerial varchar(25) NOT NULL,
   foo varchar(50),
   bar int,
   information nvarchar(250)
   date DateTime
)
```

What advantages are there for having the FOREIGN KEY workOrderID be nullable when it hasn't been used yet as opposed to being NOT NULL and having a default value of 0?
To me letting it be nullable makes more sense.

I looked at some similar situations but I'm not sure why someone would choose one over the other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a foreign key with a default value of 0, that means you must at all times maintain the existence of a workOrder with a ID of 0, as a fake-workOrder for unassigned components to reference. This is a pretty ugly hack.

(This is assuming your `FOREIGN KEY` actually is a proper, enforced foreign key, which is definitely desirable, but wouldn't happen if you were, say, using MyISAM. The example doesn't work for me, as just saying `FOREIGN KEY` on its own without specifying what column it `REFERENCES` isn't valid SQL.)

If you don't like NULLs, the alternative solution is a join table mapping components to workOrders, with a UNIQUE constraint on the component_Id.

Comment: I don't mind nulls, I was just wondering if there was an advantage of making the foreign key NOT NULL.  From the responses I got I will make it nullable.

Answer (score 6):

The advantage of a nullable foreign key is the same as the advantage of any other nullable column:  if you have no known or applicable value to store in a given row, you can use NULL instead of electing a "special value" that signifies no value.

Comment: Yes, using a 0 or a date way out of range or an empty string on any column that should be null makes the database harder to maintain. Null means we don't know the value, 0 means something.